# PHP -Ajax : send response data to php to convert jsonp to php array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/privateTraining/getTrainingsJson",
            data: { ListID: '1'},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data)
            {

              anotherFunction(data);
            }
        });

    function anotherFunction(data){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:data,
            url:"anotherFile.php,
            success: function(data)
            {
                  //do something elese;
            }
        });   
    }
```

here first one is cross domain ajax call.

here i want to send the result (jasonp response) of first ajax call  to second ajax call to a php file .. where i need to convert jsonp data to php array .

is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Seems like it might be easier to get that cross-domain resource server-side if you're just going to be sending it there anyway. So make a single AJAX request to anotherFile.php, inside of which you make a request to the cross-domain resource for the JSON, then convert that to a PHP array, and return whatever it is you need to.

Comment: yes that is very much possible